# How do I disable the inifinite loop of ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I found this code online and tested it. It worked but it goes in an infinite loop. I saw some post about creating a new `func` for the index of the pages.

Link to the website I found the code on: http://samwize.com/2015/10/13/how-to-create-uipageviewcontroller-in-storyboard-in-container-view/

Anyone willing to edit the code so the loop ends?

```
import UIKit

class MyPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    var pages = [UIViewController]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self

        let page1: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page1")
        let page2: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page2")
        let page3: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page3")

        pages.append(page1)
        pages.append(page2)
        pages.append(page3)

        setViewControllers([page2], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!
        let previousIndex = abs((currentIndex - 1) % pages.count)

        return pages[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!
        let nextIndex = abs((currentIndex + 1) % pages.count)
        return pages[nextIndex]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: *"It worked but it goes in an infinite loop"* - that's a contradiction.

Comment: @rmaddy, Looking at the code I don't think he means an infinite loop. The code causes the last page to cycle back to the first, and the first page to cycle to the last. Not exactly an infinite loop, but an endless book. (See my answer)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Page view controllers are not supposed to wrap.

Your `viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `viewControllerAfterViewController` methods are both written to wrap around from the first to the last or last to first, which is wrong.

Simply rewrite `viewControllerBeforeViewController` to decrement `currentIndex`, and return that view controller unless it's <0. If it is <0, return nil.

Likewise for `viewControllerAfterViewController`, increment `currentIndex`, and if it's `< pages.count`, return that item, else nil.

See if you can write that code.

Comment: I can not make `viewControllerAfterViewController`to work, i can keep scrolling to the right. `viewControllerBeforeViewController ` is working like a charm, thanks. Maybe give a little line of code so i can finish `viewControllerAfterViewController`.

Comment: In the `viewControllerAfterViewController` it should be `nextIndex < 1`, Then it will work :)thanks man

Comment: That doesn't sound right. You need to make sure that the new index does not go beyond the array bounds, so in `viewControllerAfterViewController` you need to test that `nextIndex < pages.count`

Comment: Well it still works with `nextIndex < 1`, `nextIndex < pages.count` does not work for some reason, it puts it in a loop.

Comment: So post your revised code at the bottom of your question as the solution.

Answer (score 7):

### Swift 3.0

```
var pages = [UIViewController]()

extension ViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                            viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex = pages.index(of: viewController)!
        let previousIndex = currentIndex - 1
        return (previousIndex == -1) ? nil : pages[previousIndex]
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                            viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex = pages.index(of: viewController)!
        let nextIndex = currentIndex + 1
        return (nextIndex == pages.count) ? nil : pages[nextIndex]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, using a code example turn it pretty easy to understand

Answer (score -1):

```
import UIKit
```

class MyPageViewController: UIPageViewController , UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

```
var pages = [UIViewController]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self
    self.dataSource = self

    let page1: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page1")
    let page2: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page2")
    let page3: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page3")


    pages.append(page1)
    pages.append(page2)
    pages.append(page3)


    setViewControllers([page2], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {


    let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!


    let previousIndex = abs((currentIndex - 1) % pages.count)


    if (previousIndex > 0)
    {
        return nil
    }



    return pages[previousIndex]
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!
    let nextIndex = abs((currentIndex + 1) % pages.count)


    if (nextIndex < 1)
    {
        return nil
    }

    return pages[nextIndex]

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}