# Disable Scroll left & right in UIPageViewController Objective-C iOS

Tags: objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, xcode9, uipagecontrol

Hi every one i have 3 controller in my `UIPageViewController`. I just want to disable left swipe scroll from first controller and also disable right swap scroll from last controller. How can I do that?

Comment: Take a look at this link, it can be what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798218/disable-uipageviewcontroller-bounce

Comment: implement but not working.

Comment: @ShahbazAkram possiblly look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656432/how-do-i-disable-the-inifinite-loop-of-viewcontrollers this link. this may work :)

Comment: Do `dataSource = nil` and handle on swipe gesture if you want.

Comment: @AmirKhan Can you explain how i can do it?